# Sesame Seed replacement

Tags: seeds

What can I use to replace [beige] sesame seeds? What could be a close visual match?

I want to make an "everything bagel" inspired scone, but want to avoid sesame seeds due to allergy concerns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything "spice" has several ingredients.  You could simply leave them out with no ill effects.

Comment: Finely chopped nuts could be an option, but is this a sesame specific allergy concern, or would any seed or nut cause similar concern (I am thinking of conditions where many who react to any seed or kernel)?

Answer (score 10):

**Golden Flax Seeds**

Since you're only looking for a visual match, I suggest Golden Flax Seeds. The taste and texture, of course, are quite different, but they are still edible.

Here is a side by side comparison.

[image: Toasted Sesame Seeds]
Sesame seeds

[image: Golden Flax Seeds]
Flax seeds

Answer (score 3):

Quinoa seeds are somewhat visually similar to sesame when uncooked/roasted.

They are slightly more spherical, whereas sesame are flatter shaped. Texture is probably very similar too.

[image]

Lineseed are also vaguely similar, if a bit darker in color and slightly bigger in size.

[image]

Comment: Note that linseed and flaxseed are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it would be an improvement on the issue of allergies, but sunflower seeds would be a good substitute.

[image]

Comment: Sunflower seeds are not a 'close visual match' to sesame seeds.

Comment: "close" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: It's really not

Comment: Size, color... Also an opinion, but I think most would not find that a match, plus and "everything" there would be a good chance sunflower would already be included.   But then, that is a counter argument to add them and let the sesame seeds slide, close enough for some and putting them there anyway?